# Is that possible to build a Quarkus native executable with a normal JavaEE and JAX-RS Project?

Tags: maven, jax-rs, quarkus, java-ee-8

Let's say I've a project, which is about JavaEE and JAX-RS and normally deployed on wildfly. And now I need to implement Quarkus native.

So here is what I have:

A JavaEE project, which so far has no relation with Quarkus.

What I want to do:

1.Implement Quarkus native with a POM.

Is that possible ? Any Suggestions or Answers would be appealed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most JavaEE applications can be converted to Quarkus fairly easily as Quarkus has support for the most important JavaEE specs.

There are also various articles you can read up on. See [this](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2019/04/12/migrating-java-applications-to-quarkus-lessons-learned#), [this](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2020/09/11/quarkus-and-jakarta-ee-together-or-not) and [this](https://engineering.talkdesk.com/one-year-of-quarkus-at-talkdesk-ed597821c102).
You can also check out the [Migration Toolkit for Applications](https://quarkus.io/blog/migrating-existing-apps-to-quarkus-with-mta/) which provides insights on migrating existing applications to Quarkus.